# задание условия в цикле

Tags: c, математика, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Есть некоторая игра- программа должна угадывать число, которые вы загадали путем вопросов :меньше оно или больше . Если число всегда больше , то задания пределов в рандоме работает корректно , а вот когда меньше - неправильно.
Как корректно задать пределы для условия , когда число меньше?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PREDEL 100

int main ()
{
  //int yes=1; //yes or higher
  //int no=2;  //no or lower
  int otvet; //answer for main
  int otvet_2;//answer for support
    int i=0;
    printf("Hello!I will share u number from 1 too 100!");
  srand ( time(NULL) );
    int secret [100]={0} ;
        secret[0]=rand()%PREDEL + 1; //random number
        printf("Is your number is %d?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret[0]);
            scanf("%d",&otvet);
            while(otvet!= 1)
            {

               printf("Are your number higher or lower than %d?\n1-higher 2-lower\n",secret[i]);
                scanf("%d",&otvet_2);
                    if (otvet_2==1)
                    {
                      srand ( time(NULL) );
                            secret[i+1]=rand()%(100-secret[i]) + (secret[i]+1);
                    }
                else
                {
                 srand ( time(NULL) );
                            secret[i+1]=rand()%(100-(secret[i-1]-secret[i] )) + (secret[i]);
                }
                printf("Are your number is %d ?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret[i+1]);
                scanf("%d",&otvet);
                i++;
            }
        printf("\nYES!I win!Your number is %d",secret[i]);
}
```

Comment: `if (otvet_2=1)` - и что, по-вашему, это за проверка?

Comment: printf("Are your number higher or lower than %d?\n1-higher 2-lower\n",secret[i]); 1-означает, что число больше

Comment: Сравнение на равенство в языке С делается через оператор `==`. Оператор `=` - это не сравнение вообще. Поэтому еще раз: что вы хотели сказать вашим `if (otvet_2=1)`?

Comment: Вообще работает и так , но я исправил на == . Мой вопрос от этого не поменялся никак

Comment: Что значит "работает и так"? В варианте "и так" вторая ветка `if` не будет вызваться никогда. Соответственно вопросы про какие-то пределы в этой второй ветке бессмысленны - они ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Я говорю я поменял - вопрос мой от этого не изменился !

Comment: Это к вопросу не относится, но `srand( time(NULL) );` вызывается **один раз**, лучше - в начале программы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PREDEL 100

int main ()
{
    //int yes=1; //yes or higher
    //int no=2;  //no or lower
    int otvet; //answer for main
    int otvet_2;//answer for support
    int low = 1, high = PREDEL;
    int otschet=1;
    printf("Hello!I'll guess your number from 1 too 100!\n");
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int secret = rand()%(high-low+1) + low; //random number
    printf("Is your number is %d?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret);
    scanf("%d",&otvet);
    while(otvet!= 1)
    {
        printf("Are your number higher or lower than %d?\n1-higher 2-lower\n",secret);
        scanf("%d",&otvet_2);
        if (otvet_2==1)
        {
            low = secret;
            if(secret>97){
                    secret = rand()%(high-low) + (low+1);
            }
            else
            secret = rand()%(high-low-1) + (low+1);
             //srand ( time(NULL) );
        }
        else
        {
            high = secret;
            if(secret<4){
                secret = rand()%(high-low) + (low);
            }
            else
            secret = rand()%(high-low-1) + (low+1);
        }

         //srand ( time(NULL) );
         otschet++;
        printf("Are your number is %d ?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret);
        scanf("%d",&otvet);
    }
    printf("\nYES!I win in %d attempt's!Your number is %d",otschet,secret);
    return 0;
}
```

Поправил пределы и добавил парочку if'ов и всё заработало отлично ! Спасибо , Mikhailo за идею !

Comment: Что за магические числа `97` и `4`, откуда они взялись и к чему они тут? Зачем понадобились эти `if`-ы???

Comment: по три крайних значения , если не добавлять эти условия , то либо: -не будет искать крайние числа ,либо-будет повторять некоторые значения . Так вроде всё работает

Comment: Если правильно написать вычисление значения, то все будет прекрасно находить и не будет никаких повторений. Уже само возникновение каких-то левых магических значений `4` и `97`, говорит о том, что написана чушь. Также умиляет существование макро-константы `PREDEL`. Именнованные константы создаются для того, чтобы их было легко исправлять. Ну и как вы будете теперь исправлять этот `PREDEL`, скажем на `1000`, если в коде уже жестко прошито какое-то левое `97`?

Comment: ну я уже поменял значения на Predel +-3 . Ну я тип только встал на путь программиста )

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно вычисляете новое значение. И вообще, вам нужно не только предыдущее значение, а два - наибольшее и наименьшее  из загаданных. И выбирать новое между ними. Вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PREDEL 100

int main ()
{
    //int yes=1; //yes or higher
    //int no=2;  //no or lower
    int otvet; //answer for main
    int otvet_2;//answer for support
    int low = 1, high = PREDEL;
    printf("Hello!I will share u number from 1 too 100!\n");
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int secret = rand()%(high-low+1) + low; //random number
    printf("Is your number is %d?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret);
    scanf("%d",&otvet);
    while(otvet!= 1)
    {
        printf("Are your number higher or lower than %d?\n1-higher 2-lower\n",secret);
        scanf("%d",&otvet_2);
        if (otvet_2==1)
        {
            low = secret;
            secret = rand()%(high-low+1) + low;
        }
        else
        {

            high = secret;
        }
        secret = rand()%(high-low+1) + low;
        printf("Are your number is %d ?\n1-yes 2-no\n",secret);
        scanf("%d",&otvet);
    }
    printf("\nYES!I win!Your number is %d",secret);
}
```

Я еще убрал лишние `srand`ы. В вашем случае это не так важно, человек очень часто вводить не будет числа, но все равно они лишние.

Comment: Да ,спасибо , так лучше стало ! Но всё же кажется нужно оставить srand ы . А ещё мне пару ошибки выдавало всё равно . Сейчас буду разбираться почему .

Comment: Не ясно, зачем присваивание `secret = rand()%(high-low+1) + low;` сохранено в первой ветке `if`, если сразу за этим `if` оно все равно делается. В любом случае, реализация ошибочна, ибо может генерировать одно и то же число даже после того, как пользователь сказал, что число неправильное. То есть в данной реализации процесс угадывания "не сходится" и теоретически может продолжаться вечно.